# Angular - Unit-test HttpErrorResponse with custom headers (HttpClientTestingModule)

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-httpclient

I have the following code in which I look for a custom header on error:

```
login(credentials: Credentials): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(loginUrl, credentials)
        .pipe(
            catchError((httpErrorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                let error = new Error('', httpErrorResponse.status);

                ...
                if (httpErrorResponse.headers.get('customHeaderName')) {
                    error.message = 'Appropriate Response';
                }
                ...
                return throwError(error);
            })
        );
}
```

I am using `HttpClientTestingModule` and trying to test this as follows:

```
it('should catch error with custom header', (done) => {
    authService.login(credentials)
        .subscribe({
            next: null,
            error: (error: Error) => {
                expect(error.message).toEqual('Appropriate Response');
            }
        });

    httpMock.expectOne({
        url: apiUrl,
        method: 'POST'
    }).flush([], {status: 403, statusText: 'Forbidden', headers: {'customHeaderName': 'customHeaderValue'}});

    done();
});
```

Not sure where the issue is but `status` and `statusText` come through as expected, but headers are not included so the if block is not activated.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

It should work. Here is a working example using `angular` v11+

E.g.

`auth.service.ts`:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

type Credentials = any;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  login(credentials: Credentials): Observable<any> {
    const loginUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/login';
    return this.http.post(loginUrl, credentials).pipe(
      catchError((httpErrorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        let error = new Error('' + httpErrorResponse.status);
        if (httpErrorResponse.headers.get('customHeaderName')) {
          error.message = 'Appropriate Response';
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

`auth.service.spec.ts`:

```
import {
  HttpClientTestingModule,
  HttpTestingController,
} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

fdescribe('60381453', () => {
  let authService: AuthService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [AuthService],
    });
    authService = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });
  it('should catch error with custom header', () => {
    const credentials = { password: '123', email: 'teresa.teng@example.com' };
    const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/login';
    authService.login(credentials).subscribe({
      next: null,
      error: (error: Error) => {
        expect(error.message).toEqual('Appropriate Response');
      },
    });

    httpMock.expectOne({ url: apiUrl, method: 'POST' }).flush([], {
      status: 403,
      statusText: 'Forbidden',
      headers: { customHeaderName: 'customHeaderValue' },
    });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

[image]